# Conduct experiments "more seriously"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was writing about a project I'll be starting during December.

What I want to communicate is the following.

**1)** During that month I will be conducting "preliminary experiments" (i  e., testing the set up, preparing preliminary data register and analysis, etc) and 
if everything goes as I expect.

**2)** I'll be doing "more serious" research (i e., designing and conducting "the real experiments")

I need it to be relatively short so I can't explain in detail everything. I have written a very simple phrase but it doesn't sound right, there's something in the second part that sounds strange. Also, it seems that during December I will be fooling around instead of doing "serious" research while both parts are crucial.

> I will be starting experiments during December, hopefully more seriously during the beginning of 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will run experiments starting from December 2015. Preliminary work
>   in the first few weeks will *lead to*/*prepare the way for* the first
>   data collections in early 2016.

By the way, it is recommendable to be as specific as possible, so the generic *experiment* or *data collection* or similar terms might be replaced by something closer to the actual tasks, e.g. *crystal growth*, *thin-film deposition*, etc.

Comment: Thank you, your version is more clear and I believe I should be more specific. I would like to enlarge the phrase but word count is already above limit, I'll have to shrink my phases.

Comment: In general, you can save a lot of words by avoiding general terms (which need to be specified later) and passives. It's also okay to avoid using _presence of_ or _occurrence of_ and keeping the bare subject, as well as the bare quantity instead of the _trend_ of that quantity. Just a couple of tricks.